# Sort by specific column but keep items with same primary index together

Tags: python, pandas

If I had a dataframe like below, where user and item are the indices.

```
user        item        value
2           a           5555
            b           7777
3           c           9999
            d           2222
1           e           6666
```

How would I approach such that values are sorted accordingly, but if two items have the same user they are kept together regardless?

```
user        item        value
3           c           9999
            d           2222
2           b           7777
            a           5555
1           e           6666.
```

To get something like above. It is sorted by largest value for user, but items with same user are kept together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to sort by max value in each group, then by the value of each row:

```
# max value for each user
df['max_val'] = df.groupby('user')['value'].transform('max')
(df.sort_values(['max_val', 'user', 'value'], ascending=False)
   .drop('max_val', axis=1) # drop the max value 
)
```

output:

```
           value
user item       
3    c      9999
     d      2222
2    b      7777
     a      5555
1    e      6666
```